# Video on demand streaming to various end user devices with AWS Cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, video-streaming, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elastic-transcoder, video-on-demand

I want to implement video on demand streaming to multiple devices such as android, ios devices and browsers html5.
Is this possible with AWS Cloudfront? I’m a little bit confused with the different streaming protocols for the various devices. How does AWS Cloudfront and AWS Elastic Transcoder handles this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upload the all videos on S3 and setup the job pipeline to transcode the videos and store back them on S3 bucket. for the transcoding you can use Amazon Elastic Transcoder services (On AWS Console) where you can find the proper transcoding parmameters that wold be supportable to all major browsers and devices.

there after you need to create the CloudFront distribution for these converted videos, On cloudFront services you would be able to see the web/RTMP type distribution to create for the bucket content access.

Comment: Oke I understand, thanks. So i.e I have a website that serves different movies to my customers and one of my customers clicks on a movie link to watch it. Does he get a URL for that specific movie to stream it from the edge location to the user? How does that work?

Comment: If i am getting your points correctly, you want to prevent "Hot Linking of the videos" So user would not be able to copy the URL of the video and direct stream on browsers. for that issue you can use the S3 bucket policy to restrict the content out side your domain.hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track of streaming with CloudFront.
Amazon Elastic Encoder does all the encoding for you, but all transcoding need to done offline, not realtime.

Once the transcoding is done, then deliver the respective file to the caller based on the device type.

**Video Streaming Tutorials:**

https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/streaming/

**AWS Elastic Encoder:**

https://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/

Hope it helps.

Comment: How does CloudFront know which protocol to use because I'm VOD streaming to differnent end devices such as IOS, android and browsers.@kannaiyan